# c3p0 more faster in Eclipse and more slow in .jar

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, hibernate

I have a Java Swing desktop system, and I try to use the c3p0 for resource pool. In Eclipse, the time for connection in remote MySQL hosted in DigitalOcean droplet is 8 seconds, because the c3p0 use 4 pool connections. The image below show 4 C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager:

[image]

But in Jar distribution file, the time for connect in database is over 22 seconds. I try to use BoneCP and others providers (like HikariCP) and not working for me in remote database. My Hibernate configuration file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration  
 PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- local connection properties -->

    <!-- Firebird
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
    -->

    <!-- MYSQL -->

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initial_pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_pool_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">180</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">4</property>

    <!-- 
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
     -->

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>         

    <!-- mapping classes -->

    <mapping class="core.UsNameView" />

</session-factory>
```

Edit: i include more information of my desktop Java program:

```
            Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();

        //String tipoAtualizacaoT = "update";
        // tipoAtualizacaoT = "validate";
        // tipoAtualizacaoT = "create";
        String tipoAtualizacaoT = "none";

        conf.configure("/conexaoMySQL/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .setProperty(
                        "hibernate.connection.url",
                        "jdbc:mysql://" + Principal.connectionHost
                                + ":3306/" + Principal.databaseName)
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "user")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "valPassword")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", tipoAtualizacaoT);

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

And my sourcecode in Login frame (in test connection):

```
        SessionFactory sessionFactory1;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration()
            .configure();

    conf.configure("/conexaoMySQL/hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .setProperty(
                    "hibernate.connection.url",
                    "jdbc:mysql://"
                            + Principal.connectionHost
                            + ":3306/"
                            + Principal.databaseName)
            .setProperty(
                    "hibernate.connection.username",
                    "val")
            .setProperty(
                    "hibernate.connection.password",
                    "valPass")
            .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                    "none");

    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(conf.getProperties())
            .build();
    sessionFactory1 = conf
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    DAOPrincipal<UsuariosNome> dao = new DAOPrincipal<UsuariosNome>(
            sessionFactory1);

    UsNameView usrV = (UsNameView) dao
            .recuperarPorCampoID(UsNameView.class,
                    "name", "ADMIN");

    System.out.println(usrV.getId() + " - "
            + usrV.getNome());

    labelConnection.setText("Conected");
```

And dao function:

```
private SessionFactory factory;

@PersistenceContext(name = "default")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public DAOPrincipal(SessionFactory sessao) throws Exception {
    factory = sessao;
}

public Object recuperarPorCampoID(Class<T> classePersistente,
        String nomeCampo, String valor) {
    Session sessao = factory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = sessao.createCriteria(classePersistente);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(nomeCampo, valor));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    Object objeto = criteria.uniqueResult();
    sessao.close();
    return objeto;
}

public Object recuperarPorId3(Class<T> classePersistente, Integer pk)
        throws Exception {
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Object objeto = session.get(classePersistente, pk);
    session.flush();

    session.close();
    return objeto;
}
```

I don't understand why my Jar application have a 22 seconds delay to connect in DigitalOcean MySQL database, and a hibernate default configuration have a 8 seconds delay to connect.

Comment: On the same computer and network?

Comment: Yes. My jar is more slow to connect the Digital Ocean MYSQL database. More than 20 seconds using c3p0 configuration.

Comment: Your cloud database? How is that the same computer and network?

Comment: I include more information in question. I am in desktop homeoffice computer, and my database is hosted in DigitalOcean droplet, with MySQL database. A hibernate default configuration have a 8 seconds delay to connect, and C3P0 configuration in Hibernate config file causes 22 seconds delay to connect in database hosted remotely. The delay is only in jar file. In Eclipse, the delay with C3P0 is only 8 seconds, because i think the Eclipse create 4 pool connections. But my knowledge in C3P0 is very small.

Comment: have look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716017/connection-pooling-in-java-using-c3p0